# python variable as a name of list item

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list:

```
 topics = ['topic1', 'topic2', 'topic3']
```

and a dict with links to topics values index:

```
 values = {'my_value' : "topics[2]", 'your_value': "topics[0]"}
```

of cause, that statement will not work, but the idea is to have a dictionary where values will be values from required list.

Yes, it looks like I have to write simple statement:

```
values = {'my_value' : topics[2], 'your_value': topics[0]}
```

but unfortunately, i don't have a ref to the list initially.
it is better to say that at the begining, i have only "values" and then, list "topics" will be set up.

as result, I would like to have dictionary:

```
 values = {'my_value': 'topic3', 'your_value': 'topic1'}
```

Comment: did you mean `values = {'my_value' : topics[2], 'your_value': topics[0]}` ?

Comment: I updated my question to make it more clear. I have topics after "values" was defined.

Comment: Does `topics` actually have to be a top-level object that way? could it be stored instead like: `topics_dict = {"topics": ["topic1", "topic2", "topic3"]}`? If so, then you could use regular-expression on `"topics[2]"` and separate the `variable` and the `index`.

Comment: topics is top level, you are right. but It can't be changed. the structure set up externally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `eval` as follows:

```
topics = ['topic1', 'topic2', 'topic3']
values = {'my_value' : "topics[2]", 'your_value': "topics[0]"}
new_values = {k:eval(v) for (k, v) in values.items()}
print(new_values)
```

**Note**: this required that `topics` variable to be defined, and the value in `values` dictionary to be executable

**Update**:

As noted in comments by @matt, its more secure to get only indices. We can do this using regex expression(As noted by @HampusLarsson), we can do the following:

```
 new_vals = {k:int(re.findall("\d+", v)[0]) for (k, v) in values.items()}
 values = {k:topics[v] for (k, v) in new_vals.items()}
```

Comment: this will work but it is not a good idea to evaluate arbitrary strings as it is a security risk. Maybe it would be better to mangle the index from the string and call the list directly instead: `new_values = {k: topics[int(v[7:-1])] for (k, v) in values.items()}`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotation marks. A dictionary does not have to contain strings. You can add a reference to the list item instead.

```py
values = {'my_value' : topics[2], 'your_value': topics[0]}
```

Comment: sorry, i wasn't clear in my question. Initially, i don't have a reference to topics list. Will update my question